# How get hippo version?

Tags: java, hippocms

Yep I logined to hippo console `localhost:8080/cms/console/` as described [here](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/content-repository/using-the-console.html) what is next? There is a tree with conponents and no button or link like `about` or `settings`.

1. Is it possible to get hippo version information from hippo console?
2. If no how get it version otherwise?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it not about programming problem.

Comment: ok can it be moved to superuser site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the console (which is really a low level tool) go to the normal admin area:

```
localhost:8080/cms/
```